# Checking for evens on a list, and getting a type mismatch in Scala

Tags: scala, function, for-loop, user-defined-functions, flow-control

I'm trying to check the contents of a list to see if an element is even or not. Here is the code:

```
def listEvenChecker2(aList: List[Int]): Boolean = 
{
    for (elem <- aList)
    {
        if (elem % 2 == 0)
        {
           return true
        }
        else 
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}

val myList = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
println(listEvenChecker2(myList))
```

Why am I getting this error:

[image]

Comment: `myList.forall(_ % 2 == 0)`

Comment: `return` is not necessary in **Scala** and it is even a bad practice. The problem in this case is that, even if the code is _"correct"_ the typechecker sees that you are returning `Unit` from the _for each_. I would recommend you to follow the [**tour of scala**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html) so you can familiarize with the syntax. - Finally, *Scala's **List** is designed for recursion, which I believe is what you should be using here.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why my solution is not working. I know that if I remove the ```else``` block and place it outside the for-loop this works, but I don't think I understand why. Someone with that insight help.

Comment: First your code doesn't do what you want it to do, since it will just check the first element. Second, you have to understand that `for (x <- gen) { block }` is equivalent to `gen.foreach(x => block)` So at the end, it is just applying some side effect to all the element of the list... which is not what you want. Take a look to the **tour** and try to implement your code using _recursion_ if you get stuck edit the question and tag me.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll take a look at the tour.

Comment: Are you checking if any element of the list is even or if all the elements are even?

Comment: I should have been more specific: Write a function that returns True if there is an even number inside of a list, otherwise return False.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you what to check whether there is at least one even value, use `exists`:

```
def listEvenChecker2(aList: List[Int]): Boolean = 
  aList.exists(_%2 == 0)
```

If you want to check that they are all even, use `forall`:

```
def listEvenChecker2(aList: List[Int]): Boolean = 
  aList.forall(_%2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the scala docs on [for-comprehensions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html#translating-for-comprehensions), it shows an example:

> #### EXAMPLE 1
>
> ```
> for(x <- c1; y <- c2; z <-c3) {...}
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> c1.foreach(x => c2.foreach(y => c3.foreach(z =>{...})))
> ```

As you can see, the for-expression you have is tranformed into a [`aList.foreach`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foreach[U](f:A=%3EU):Unit) call which returns `Unit` instead of `Boolean`